# Creating a habtm relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm creating a movie watchlist app in rails/angular. For this I have a table with users and a table with movies.

At the moment I create a unique record for each movie added, this results in several copies of existing records but all with different user id's. So I'm looking into the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in rails. But I'm having some trouble using it in my app.

As I see it a user can have multiple movies, and a movie can have multiple users. So I've added this to the models,

movie.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

user.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :movies
```

I've also created a migration,

```
class AddMoviesUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :movies_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :movie_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :movies_users
  end
end
```

But I'm unsure on how this is all connected. With the migration I've added a join table with 2 colums. Movie_id and user_id. Does the `movie_id` value in the `movie_users` table correspond to the `movie_id` in the `movie table`? Same goes for the `user_id`, does that correspond to the `user_id` in the `user table`?

Also, how do I connect the two id's together. Do I have to add "something" to the `movies_users` join table when I create a new movie?

This is my current movies_controller.rb

```
def create
  respond_with Movie.create(movie_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
end

private
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :image, :release_date, :movie_id)
end
```

**//EDIT//**

I've added the `has_many_belongs_to` relations to my movie and user model and I created a join table called `movies_users` with 2 colums `user_id` and `movie_id`.

I've created 2 accounts on my page and added the movie Creed with them. This is the result in my rails console `Movie.all`

```
#<Movie id: 1, title: "Creed", user_id: 1, movie_id: "312221">, 
#<Movie id: 2, title: "Creed", user_id: 2, movie_id: "312221">
```

As you can see it still creates 2 different movies although they have the same values, except the user_id. So it looks like there's no checking to see if an value (the `movie_id`) already exists. I thought this was a part of the habtm relation.

Comment: Did you read the AR guide on HABTM? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: I have. But it doesn't explain how to set up the controllers needed for this to work.

Comment: the `movie_id` from `movie_users` points to the automatically generated primary-key `id` of `movies`. Vice verca with `user_id`.

Comment: @marczking That confirms what I thought, but I'm still unclear on the connection between the movie table, user table and movie_user table. Also I'm unclear on how to create a controller to get this going.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Did you ever solve this?  From your edit it perhaps seems like you have a validation problem.  Is movie_id set up to be unique?  how is movie_id separate from id in the movie table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than habtm i would use `has_many :through`

```
class User
  has_many :movies_users
  has_many :movies, :through => :movies_users

class Movie
  has_many :movies_users
  has_many :users, :through => :movies_users  

class MoviesUser
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
```

Now you will have a single movie record per movie and create a movie_user record when a user watches a movie.  You can do this RESTfully with a MoviesUsersController, which you call the create action, passing through `params = {:movies_user => {:user_id => 123, :movie_id => 456}}`

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to use `habtm` in your case if you need the join table only for  relationships and don't need to store extra information in the joining table. In this c\\ase records of the joining table (movies_users) are created automatically, while you are using given by the `has_and_belongs_to_many` methods.

Your `create` action may look like this:

```
def create
   movie = Movie.create(movie_params)
   current_user.movies << movie
   ...
end
```

or like this:

```
def create
   current_user.movies.create(movie_params)
   ...
end
```

**Added after the question updated**

You don't need `movie_id` and `user_id` fields in your Movie model. This all should look like this:

```
movie = Movie.last
#<Movie id: 1, title: "Creed">

user = User.last
#<User id: 1, name: "Username", ...>

# add the movie to the user's watch list
user.movies << movie

# a record in the joining table will be created automatically
#<user_id: 1, movie_id: 1>
```

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand, but I still have a question. I've updated my question to give some more information about the question.